# Как сделать проверку на файл конфига

Tags: python, config

У меня есть конфигурационный файл `config.ini` вот его содержание

```
[Browser]
chrome= 55, 755
huiman= 702, 469
```

но как сделать проверки на его наличие, и если при отсутствии его наличия, создавать его с таким вот содержанием

```
[Browser]
chrome= Place your coordinates
huiman= Place your coordinates
```

вот для чего это надо

```
import pyautogui as pag
import configparser

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read("config.ini")

def chrome_mail():
    pag.moveTo(config["Browser"]["chrome"])
    pag.click()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    chrome_mail()
```

Comment: Просто `if not os.path.exists('config.ini')` наверное?

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: @S.Nick обновил.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Используйте блок `try/except`

```py
import pyautogui as pag
import configparser

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
try:
    config.read("config.ini")
except:
    file = open("config.ini", "w", encoding="utf8")
    file.write("[Browser]\n"
               "chrome= Place your coordinates\n"
               "huiman= Place your coordinates")
    file.close()
    config.read("config.ini")

def chrome_mail():
    pag.moveTo(config["Browser"]["chrome"])
    pag.click()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    chrome_mail()
```

Теперь если файл `config.ini` не существует, он автоматически создатся

Comment: почему вы решили что стока `config.read("config.ini")` должна вызвать исключение?

Comment: @S.Nick, другие не могут

Comment: если файла `config.ini` нет, то эта строка `config.read("config.ini")` формирует пустой список `[]` и никакого исключения не будет.